# ValueError (while creating a function in python): The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
def function(df):
    if (df['Total'] > 0) & (df['Total'] <= 50000):
         df['X'] = (df['Total']*(2/150)) * 0.2
    elif (df['Total'] > 50000):
        df['X'] = ((50000*(2/150))*0.2) + ((df['Total']-50000)*(2/150)*0.2)
```

I am trying to run the above code but getting a value error saying

```
File "<ipython-input-31-f77514d81c6f>", line 1, in <module>
    platinumplus(cust_spends)

File "<ipython-input-30-da2fd213761f>", line 2, in platinumplus
    if (df['Total'] > 0) & (df['Total'] <= 50000):

File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", 
    line 1573, in __nonzero__ .format(self.__class__.__name__))
```

> **ValueError**: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Can you show us the stack trace?

Comment: Can you please show the data set?

Comment: Please, chech that `df['Total']` type is float. It might be string

Comment: File "<ipython-input-31-f77514d81c6f>", line 1, in <module>
    platinumplus(cust_spends)

  File "<ipython-input-30-da2fd213761f>", line 2, in platinumplus
    if (df['Total'] > 0) & (df['Total'] <= 50000):

  File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1573, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @Abhaykumar Then can you please post it on the question, edit it then add it?

Comment: @jalazbe data type is integer.

Comment: @jezrael Can you explain why you reopened a question which lacks MCVE and a clear duplicate?

Comment: @ayhan - I think this is better dupe like before.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is in your `if` statements. `(df['Total'] > 0) & (df['Total'] <= 50000)` will return a boolean series rather than a single `True` or `False` so python doesn't know how to handle this. If you want the case where **all** of the values in the series are `True` you can use:

`((df['Total'] > 0) & (df['Total'] <= 50000)).all()`

Comment: it partially worked, 2nd loop is not working.

Comment: So I think this answer addresses the source of the error (you would have to use the same logic on your second if statement). However it looks like this might not be doing what you expect - setting values based on how they evaluate in the series for which I suggest you look at the solution using `numpy.where`

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for set new values of column by boolean mask:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Total':[10, 10000, 40000, 100]})

def function(df):
    mask = (df['Total'] > 0) & (df['Total'] <= 50000)
    v1 = (df['Total']*(2/150)) * 0.2
    v2 = ((50000*(2/150))*0.2) + ((df['Total']-50000)*(2/150)*0.2)

    df['X'] = np.where(mask, v1, v2)
    return df

df1 = df.pipe(function)
print (df1)
   Total           X
0     10    0.026667
1  10000   26.666667
2  40000  106.666667
3    100    0.266667
```

If there is multiple conditions use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Total':[10, 10000, 40000, 100, -2]})


def function(df):
    mask1 = (df['Total'] > 0) & (df['Total'] <= 50000)
    mask2 = df['Total'] > 50000
    v1 = (df['Total']*(2/150)) * 0.2
    v2 = ((50000*(2/150))*0.2) + ((df['Total']-50000)*(2/150)*0.2)

    df['X'] = np.select([mask1, mask2], [v1, v2], default=np.nan)
    return df

df1 = df.pipe(function)
print (df1)
   Total           X
0     10    0.026667
1  10000   26.666667
2  40000  106.666667
3    100    0.266667
4     -2         NaN
```

Comment: what if there is one more elif condition?

Comment: @Abhaykumar - added solution. If new elif condition create new boolean mask and new values `mask3` with `v3`.

Comment: @jpp - I agree, thank you.